# Alamofire: finished with error - code: -1001

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, request, alamofire

Code like this:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
struct Request {
var alamoFireManager : SessionManager?
init() {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
            configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 20
    configuration.requestCachePolicy = .useProtocolCachePolicy
            alamoFireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
}

func sendRequest() {

    alamoFireManager?.request(url,method: method, parameters: body, encoding: JSONEncoding.default,headers: headers).responseJSON { response in

    }
}
}
```

Comment: I think its Request time out error.

Comment: NSURLErrorDomain code = -1001 clearly states that request time out. You have specified `timeoutIntervalForRequest` to your session as 20 hence the error, in your answer you posted below you are not setting any timeout interval hence it works. So mentioning SessionManager does not work is incorrect. Either post correct answer by increasing/removing time interval on SessionManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***`SessionManager`*** not works for me correctly. It's better to using code like this in **Alamofire**:

```
let request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
//Some configuration


Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON {
                response in

}
```

Answer (score 3):

**I have done this and it's working (swift 4 Code).**

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class SplashViewController: UIViewController {

    var alamoFireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.callPostApi()

    }

    func callPostApi() {

        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 20 // seconds
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 20
        configuration.requestCachePolicy = .useProtocolCachePolicy
        alamoFireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)

        alamoFireManager.request(url, method: .post, parameters: ["jsondata":base64EncodedString])
            .responseJSON { response in

                switch (response.result) {
                case .success:

                    print(response.data as? Data)

                    if let json = response.result.value {
                        print("JSON: \(json)") // Here is your JSON Response
                    }
                    //do json stuff

                case .failure(let error):

                    if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut || error._code == -1005{
                        //HANDLE TIMEOUT HERE
                        print("TimeOut")
                    }
                    print("\n\nAuth request failed with error:\n \(error)")
                    break
               }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: @J.DoeIt returns REQUEST TIMEOUT of your service call.

Answer (score -1):

For me was a timeout error. One option is increase the value of the timeout (bad option), the better is improve the performance of your API/Application.