# How to read data from file placed in server through url link in ios swift (4)?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios7

I have written code for retrieving data from file or download that file and show in your phone. But I don't understand why it is not displaying data. When I opened that file it shows blank and but it is printing some hexadecimal code in a console.

I am very new to this IOS development, kindly please help me this. I want to retrieve data from the server through a link, and display it on the mobile.
Thanks in advance you can help with some alternate way.

Below is my code

```
let username = "xxxx"
let password = "xyz"
let loginData = String(format: "%@:%@", username, password).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let base64LoginData = loginData.base64EncodedString()

   // create the request
let url = URL(string: "http://demo.xyz.com/dctm-rest/repositories/iol_ref2/objects/0900a1848039590d/content-media?format=crtext&modifier=&page=0")!

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginData)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let taskk = session.downloadTask(with: request) { (tempLocalUrl, response, error) in
        if let tempLocalUrl = tempLocalUrl, error == nil {
            // Success
        if let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {
                print("Success: \(statusCode)")
            }

            do {
                 let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first

                let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)

                if paths.count > 0
                {
                    documentsDirectory = paths.first!
                }
                var fileURL : URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsUrl!.absoluteString+filename)

                if(mimetype == "text/plain"){
                     fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsUrl!.absoluteString+filename+".txt")
                }else if(mimetype == "application/pdf"){
                     fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsUrl!.absoluteString+filename+".pdf")
                }


                print(fileURL)
                let dataFromURL = NSData(contentsOf: tempLocalUrl)
                dataFromURL?.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true)

                print(dataFromURL)
                 try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: tempLocalUrl, to: fileURL)


                OperationQueue.main.addOperation  {

                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
                    let documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController.init(url: fileURL)
                    documentController.delegate = self as? UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate
                    documentController.presentPreview(animated: true)

                }

            } catch (let writeError) {
                print("error writing file  : \(writeError)")
            }

        } else {
            print("Failure: %@", error?.localizedDescription);
        }
    }
    taskk.resume()
```

Comment: **Try this One** https://stackoverflow.com/a/51609885/10150796

Comment: thus it will work for every mime type of file?? @Nikunj Kumbhani

Comment: Maybe your file isn't correctly written. `write(toFile:atomically:)` returns a Bool. Could you check its value? Or maybe use `write(toFile:options:)` which throws an error in case of fail.

Comment: Yes @Ashishyadav it's a common method for any .post or .get request.

Comment: yes @Larme you were right it is unable to write the content to file . What   else i can do and why it is not writing?

Comment: Did you use the method throwing an error? Which error is thrown?

Comment: I have check through write(toFile:atomically:) so it is returning false.

Comment: @Larme It is throwing this error "Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"

Comment: @Nikunj Kumbhani Can you please help me how to store that data in file and show into file

Comment: @Ashishyadav can you get the response by using that?

Comment: yes i was getting response @Nikunj Kumbhani

Comment: That's good @Ashishyadav now you need help for how to fetch data from response Right?

Comment: yes response.data giving optiona(some bytes) . Now i need to fetch those things in one file and open it @Nikunj Kumbhani

Comment: The code which i have written above was also giving data in console but unable to put those data in file and open it ... @Nikunj Kumbhani

Comment: @Ashishyadav the response data is in byte formate you need to get value from that for an actual response check **success** Block in my Answer update it.

Comment: Issue is with i am unable to copy my content to file and read it @Nikunj Kumbhani .... and thus it will work if any image is present in file??

Comment: @Ashishyadav if your data is an image or video then you directly play it or store the path of it. and either is file formate then you only display it in a Document viewer or store the path only not possible to store the physical file as .pdf or .document format.