# How to display any extension file from server to your mobile in swift ios?

Tags: ios, swift

I am very new to this IOS swift programming. So need some suggestion and help. I am creating an app in which I have to show different file coming from the server. Below is the kind of link from which my file data is coming.

http://demo.xxxx.com/dctm-rest/repositories/iol_ref2/objects/0900a18480383d14/content-media?format=pdf&modifier=&page=0

This above link is for pdf or it can be of any type (txt, doc, img etc) so I have tried so many things but I was unable to get a result.

Solutions What I have tried:-

1. With basic auth, I am requesting URL and getting contents from the file, so I was getting data from server and printing on console but when I tried to copy that contents to one file it says unable to copy says no such file or folder exist but I have properly defined the path location. Below is my code link which I have asked earlier.

[How to read data from file placed in server through url link in ios swift (4)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51723230/how-to-read-data-from-file-placed-in-server-through-url-link-in-ios-swift-4)

2. Someone suggested using Alamofire lib that also I have used but no luck. Below is the code which I have referred.

   [Alamofire: finished with error - code: -1001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51607630/alamofire-finished-with-error-code-1001/51609885#51609885)

So let me know what I am doing is correct or not or is there any new method or way I can try. I have tried web view too. So please help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use code like this to download a file and store it locally.

```
let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(documentFilename)
    return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile])
}

Alamofire.download(url, to: destination).response { [unowned self] response in
    // check download and call completion handler
}
```

What code did you use to download the file?