# How to make a HTTPPost request with String in swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, post, alamofire

I came across some problem, that is I am making a httppost request to update data with Alamofire as far as I am sending parameters as [String: Any] all my post requests are successful. But, for one of my POST method I have to send the parameter as simple string(like "80:1,85:3,86:2") not a key/value pair as my server side is expecting a String. I've searched all over the internet and StackOverFlow but I've not find any solution. Is it possible to make a HttpPost request with String and if possible, How?

so far my code is:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: updateAchievementOrderURL)!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
let postString = sortedOrderString
let json = postString.data(using: .utf8)!
print(json)
request.httpBody = json
Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON {response in
  switch response.response?.statusCode {
  case 200?:
      print(response.result.value!)
  case 202?:
      print(response.result.value!)
  case 404?:
      print(response.result.value!)
  case 500?:
      print(response.result.value!)
  default:
      print(response.result.value!)
            }
        }
```

it is going to case 202 accepted, But is not the success case.

I have check in Postman and it is working fine if I send the string like "80:1,85:3,86:2" see below Image for reference:

[image: Postman test]

Here it is returning 200 "Ok" and working fine:

Comment: **Try this it's Working** https://stackoverflow.com/a/51609885/10150796

Comment: Try `let postString = sortedOrderString.debugDescription`.

Comment: @OOPer Thats working mate. Thank you and may I know what is the difference between normal string and string.debugDescription

Comment: It just adds double-quote to both ends, as in the picture of the postman. (And escapes some sort of special characters, but this is not the case this time.) Remember this would not be the right method when your data includes some sort of special characters. If your string contains only digits, colons and commas, `debugDescription` would work.

Comment: @OOPer Oh! thats good to know.. Thanks for the info btw