# How to send parameter as body to PUT method using Alamofire in Swift

Tags: swift, alamofire, put

[image]I would like to send the JSON parameters in the body to PUT method, how can I do it?

Please find the sample JSON below.

```
func getKOLConnections(emials : [String],phoneNumbers : [String],address : [String],completionHandler: @escaping (Data) -> Void) -> Void {

let url = URl


let parameters :[String: Any]  = ["emails": emials,
                              "phone_numbers" : phoneNumbers,
                              "addresses" : address]

let header : HTTPHeaders =   ["Authorization": "Bearer \("eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1MzQzOTY0MzYsInNlc3Npb25fa2V5IjoiYmZhYjZkZTYtNzlhMy00NDIxLTg2M2YtMTY0MGJlOTQ3NmIzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTM0NDgyODM2fQ.LGclnO9vXxiywoS8TURzcm39pyhNnpeIZ4fzOTvS-jc")",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"] 


 requestdata =  Alamofire.request(url, method: .put, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: header)
    .validate()
    .responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result{
        case .success:
            print(response.data!)

            completionHandler(response.data!)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
 }
 }
```

Comment: **Try this One** https://stackoverflow.com/a/51609885/10150796

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you:

```
    Alamofire.request(URL(string: "url")!, method: .put, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in

        // Handle your response
    }
```

Try below parameters:

```
 let parameters :[String: Any]  = ["emails": [["email" : "", "last_updated_dev" : nil, "is_primary" : nil, "last_updated_by" : nil]],
                                          "phone_numbers" : phoneNumbers,
                                          "addresses" : address]
```

Comment: i did same way but its giving me 400 error , can u give me some code or check my code ?

Comment: @Asmita Make sure your api is working properly as 400  is Bad Request error.

Comment: in postman its  working properly , may be i am doing something wrong. @iVarun

Comment: @Asmita emials,phone,addrs are in `[String]` so it will be `String array`. are you passing same as in postman

Comment: @Asmita `emails` is Array of Dictionary and you are sending array only.

Comment: @iVarun how can i write this can you put that code here

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot shows that the parameters you need to pass are:

- `emails`
- `phone_numbers`
- `addresses`

where `emails` is also a dictionary, however, you are passing `emials : [String]` to the `getKOLConnections`. You can fix it using the following signature for `getKOLConnections`:

`func getKOLConnections(emails : [String: Any],phoneNumbers : [String],address : [String],completionHandler: @escaping (Data) -> Void) -> Void`

I have changed `emails: [String]` to `emails: [String: Any]`.

`emails: [String:Any]` would have the following keys:

- `email`
- `last_updated_dev`
- `is_primary`
- `last_updated_by`